# Permanent redirection between folders with nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

On the nginx configuration file

> default

at

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

I am trying to redirect requests made to the folder "home" to another folder "jp".
Following the [nginx manual](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/), 
I tried the script below. Any ideas as to why this would't work? Thanks.

```
server{
...
    server_name _localhost;
             location /home/ {
    rewrite www.example.io/home/$ www.example.io/home/jp/ permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a permanent redirection from /home/ to /home/jp/.

The first parameter to a `rewrite` directive is a regular expression which is matched against a [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), in your case `/home/`.

You can use a `rewrite` directive, for example:

```
location /home/ {
    rewrite ^/home/$ /home/jp/ permanent;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an exact match `location` with a `return` statement, for example:

```
location = /home/ {
    return 301 /home/jp/;
}
```